# Detecting when two of the same colors collide

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection

I have a square consisting of four different colors in the middle of my scene. At the same time, I have smaller squares of the same color randomly generated from each sides of the scene with the intention of colliding with the square in the middle. (Blue to blue, yellow to yellow, etc).

My goal is to have it set up so that when a blue square collides with a blue square or any of the like, it will `.removeFromParent()`. How should I go about doing this? Will post code if necessary.

Edit:

```
 enum BodyType: UInt32 {
case blueSquare = 1
case redSquare = 2
case yellowSquare = 4
case greenSquare = 8
```

}

```
 let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

      didBeginContact() {

          switch(contactMask) {
    case BodyType.redSquare.rawValue | BodyType.redSquare.rawValue:



        let scoreLabel = childNodeWithName("scores") as! Points
        scoreLabel.increment()
       let firstNode = contact.bodyB.node

        firstNode?.removeFromParent()
    default:
        return

      } 
       }
```

Comment: I must say, interesting that you chose to use a switch like this,  I do not think I have seen any tutorial for sprite kit list it this way,  only flaw is,  what  if your contact body is using 2 masks at once

Comment: Im using Ray Wenderlichs Sprite Kit for Kids Tutorial to try and over-simplify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing you should do is set up the contactTestBitMasks & categoryBitMasks on all of your SKSpriteNodes, like this -

```
struct PhysicsCatagory {
    static let FirstPerson : UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
    static let SecondPerson : UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
}

 override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
     ...
     firstPerson.SKPhysicsBody?.catagoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.FirstPerson
     firstPerson.SKPhysicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.SecondPerson
     ...
     secondPerson.SKPhysicsBody?.catagoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.SecondPerson
     secondPerson.SKPhysicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.FirstPerson
     ...

}
```

This is just setting up the catagoryBitMask and the contactTestBitMask. The categoryBitMask will be equal to the object you are currently editing, whereas, the contactTestBitMask will be equal to the object you want the object to collide with.

Also, before we move on, we want to add the Contact Delegate to our scene.

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate{...
```

And then add the delegate to our scene -

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
      ...
       self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
      ...
```

Next, you add the didBeginContact

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let firstBody = contact.bodyA.node as! SKSpriteNode!
    let secondBody = contact.bodyB.node as! SKSpriteNode!
}
```

Lastly inside of that, test...

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let firstBody = contact.bodyA.node as! SKSpriteNode!
    let secondBody = contact.bodyB.node as! SKSpriteNode!

    if firstBody.color == secondBody.color{
     firstBody.removeFromParent()
     secondBody.removeFromParent()
}
}
```

Hope that helps! :D

Comment: 3 things, A) you need to fix the second persons bitmaks, and B)  you do not handle the scenario where 2 items that have the same color that can collide but do not want to be removed, C)  this will only remove if the color is blue, just set `firstBody.color` == `secondBody.color`

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Thanks for that! Edited a few things. I'll have to look into B a little bit more. :)

Answer (score 1):

Once you detect a collision, compare the colors of the colliding squares and if equal, call .removeFromParent().  If you post code I could try to give the specific methods that would help.

If you want to get fancy you could create a subclass for your squares with a colorTag property (1 = blue, 2 = yellow ect.) and then compare the tags of the colliding squares.  Although I doubt the cost of comparing the colors is much.

Comment: Edited per request. I also have the `categoryBitMask, collisionBitMask & contactTestBitMask` set up for each node.

Comment: The cost of comparing color would be virtually the same as comparing the tag, the color value is stored as an Int32 (or is it UInt32)

Comment: The | operator is a bitwise logical or so BodyType.redSquare.rawValue | BodyType.redSquare.rawValue is the same as BodyType.redSquare.rawValue.  ex. 0001 | 0001 = 0001

Put in some debugging print statements and see if the values are what you expect. The cases inside your switch statement should be case 1: //blue collision case 2: //red collision case 4: //yellow collision case 8: //green collision